# Accessing live data created by jQuery in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a method in my jQuery code which generates rows and add them to my table in html as follows (and works fine):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#textDateAndTime").datetimepicker();
$(document).on("click","#ulInvite li h6",function(){
    var h=this;
    var selected=h.innerText.split(' ')[0];
    var myExp=new RegExp(selected,"i");
    $.getJSON("json_data.php",function(data){
        $.each(data,function(key,val){
            if((val.username.search(myExp))==0){
                var output="<tr>"
                    +"<td>"+val.username+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+val.firstName+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+val.lastName+"</td>"
                    +"</tr>";
                $("#tableInvite").append(output);
                h.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(h.parentNode);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my table in the html file which is simple:

```
<table name="tableInvite" id="tableInvite" border="1px solid black">
</table>
```

Then I want to use the generated rows in my php file, which is called in `<form>` tag in html by method `post`. I use `simple_html_dom.php` file to parse my table with `find` method, but it don't get `<td>` elements because they were generated by jQuery, while it would get them fine if those were in html file originally.

```
require('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('add_meeting.html');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
    $username = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
    $firstname = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;
    $lastname = $row->find('td',2)->plaintext;
}
```

but it never gets to `foreach` because it can't find any `<tr>` elements there.

So, how can I access those rows generated live?

Thanks.

Comment: What line in your posted code is line 21?

Comment: $username = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;

same error for lines 22 and 23, but no errors for line 20.

Comment: You can't (using only PHP) - duplicated : [pull-content-from-an-external-website-generated-by-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656181/pull-content-from-an-external-website-generated-by-javascript)

Comment: Assuming you are using [PHP Simple HTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find), it would help to check for a `null` return from `find()`. `TH` and `TD` are usually mutually exclusive so probably won't appear on the same `TR`  row. Indeed, your example data above has `TH` in one table, and `TD` in another.

Comment: @KenY-N you're right, I took away the `<tr>` row with `<th>` elements in it, now it just pass the `foreach` and I get no errors, because it can't find any rows in the file.